# How to get the path to the Android assets folder in the application package

Tags: android

I have a whole folder structure that I want to copy from my assets folder.  However, the mContext.getAssets().open() seems  to only want a filename so that it can return an InputStream, which is only suitable for copying a single file.  What I need is a File made from the folder in my assets folder so that I can recurse through all the files and folders and copy them all.

Does anybody know how to get the path to the assets folder so that I can create a File object?

Edit: After some study it appears that you can't access files in the assets/ and raw/ folders with absolute paths to be able to create a File object.  It probably has to do with the encryption of the app package.  I hope someone can prove me wrong though!

Final edit:  I ended up creating an array of strings to hold the extra asset files:

```
   private static final String[] DEFAULT_ALBUM_FILES =
   {INTRO_TO_FLASHUM_DIR+"03 Never Can Say Goodbye.m4a",
    INTRO_TO_FLASHUM_DIR+"11 Bossa Baroque.m4a",
    INTRO_TO_FLASHUM_DIR+"intro fling.3gp"};
```

I then iterated through this copying each file individually using the mContext.getAssets().open() to get the InputStream.  I don't think it is currently possible to iterate through a folder in the assets using normal File operations.

Comment: What have you tried? See: http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/06/14/Android-Beginners-Intro-to-Resources-and-Assets.aspx

Comment: Yes, this describes exactly what I did.

Answer (score 5):

```
AssetManager am = con.getAssets();//u have get assets path from this code
InputStream inputStream = null;         
inputStream = am.open("file.xml");
```

**or**

```
String file_name="ur.xml"    
inputStream = am.open("foldername/"+ur);
```

Comment: Hi, is there way to get a file's path from InputStream object?

Comment: @SergeyYu, I too, have the same question. So far, I've not been able get the path from the stream. Is this solved?

Answer (score 4):

Could you move the folder to your /raw folder? Then you could use:

```
 com.your.package:raw/yourFile
```

Like this:

```
int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("com.your.package:raw/somefile.txt");
File f = new File(context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId));
```

And here's someone doing it with the assets folder:

[Android Assets with sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033902/android-assets-with-sub-folders)

```
  InputStream is = getAssets().open("subfolder/somefile.txt");
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'm going to give it a try.  I'll get back with the results.  Thanks!

Comment: The raw folder also does not appear to allow absolute path references.  As least I have not been able to figure it out...

Comment: The problem is that openRawResource() returns an InputStream and there does not seem to be a way to convert the latter to a File.  With your code I get the following error: The constructor File(InputStream) is undefined.

Comment: Ah thats because I short-cut this answer :-) Once you have the IS, you then create your File and loop round the IS feeding it into the file.  This might not be the best example: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/InputstreamToFile.shtml but gives you a hint

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am aware of this technique to convert an IS to a File.  However, how do I get the File that correspondes to a folder in the assets folder?  From  there I wish to do a file.listFiles() to get the contents of that folder and iterate through it to copy the individual files.  As it is, I have to know the contents of that folder and copy the files individually.

Comment: Hi, is there way to get a file's path from InputStream object?

Answer (score -3):

Use `file:///android_asset` for accessing the asset folder and then you can always give your subfolder there.

```
AssetManager assetManager = null;   // null ???  Get the AssetManager here.
        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = null;
        try{
           assetFileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("file:///android_asset/yourfolder/file");
                FileDescriptor fd = assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
       } catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand how to use "file:///android_asset".  Can you put this in the form of "File file = new File(...);"?

Comment: Get the assetmanager, get the assetfiledescriptor , get the filedescriptor from assetfiledescriptor.

Comment: But then how do you convert a FileDescriptor to a File?

Comment: David - did you get an answer to this? if yes, please post. ty.