# Where to save text file to be able to read it into Android project

Tags: java, android, readfile

I have looked around to find out where to save general text files for reading into my Android project, but couldn't find a definite answer. When I save my "foo.txt" file into my res/raw folder as someone suggested (I had to create the raw folder) the R.java file gets error for these lines:

```
public static final class raw {
    public static final int 1_1=0x7f050000;
}
```

This is because my file contains the string "1_1" on the first line, which I want it to have. Where in the folder structure should I put my file to be able to read it? The file is not created from Android but manually by me.

Could someone also please advise on how to read a file in the following format? I want to be able to read the Strings and numbers one by one and insert into java variables in my Android project. Is it best to separate with commas or spaces?

```
1_1
String
Int
Int String String Int Int Float Float Int Int
Int String String Int Int Float Float Int Int
Int String String Int Int Float Float Int Int
Int String String Int Int Float Float Int Int
Int String String Int Int Float Float Int Int
Int String String Int Int Float Float Int Int
```

**Updated with more code:**

```
package com.my.package;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//public class GameActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{  

private ImageButton leftPauseButton;
private ImageButton rightPauseButton;

private ImageButton leftButton1;
private ImageButton leftButton2;
private ImageButton leftButton3;

private ImageButton rightButton1;
private ImageButton rightButton2;
private ImageButton rightButton3;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);
        TextView txtView = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.testID_canBeRemoved));

            //Did not work
        //int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("com.my.package:raw/foo.txt", null, null);
        //File f = new File("com.my.package:raw/foo.txt");

            //Does not work - file.exists() returns a zero value
        File file = new File("assets/foo.txt");

        if ( file.exists() ){
            txtView.setText("Exists");
        }
        else{
            txtView.setText("Does not exist");
        }


//          InitiateUIComponents();

    }

        //This is for using another xml layout
    private void InitiateUIComponents(){

        leftPauseButton = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.leftPauseButtonID));
        rightPauseButton = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.rightPauseButtonID));

        leftButton1 = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.leftMenuButton1ID));
        leftButton2 = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.leftMenuButton2ID));
        leftButton3 = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.leftMenuButton3ID));

        rightButton1 = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.rightMenuButton1ID));
        rightButton2 = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.rightMenuButton2ID));
        rightButton3 = (ImageButton) (findViewById(R.id.rightMenuButton3ID));

        leftPauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightPauseButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        leftButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        leftButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        leftButton3.setOnClickListener(this);

        rightButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightButton3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

            //This is for using another xml layout
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.leftPauseButtonID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left pause button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rightPauseButtonID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right pause button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.leftMenuButton1ID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left menu button 1 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.leftMenuButton2ID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left menu button 2 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.leftMenuButton3ID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left menu button 3 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rightMenuButton1ID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right menu button 1 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rightMenuButton2ID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right menu button 2 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rightMenuButton3ID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right menu button 3 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;


        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the xml file for this test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/testID_canBeRemoved"
    android:text="Blabla"
>

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First**: `1_1` is not a valid variable name. As per the Java Documentation:

> > A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

**Second**: The file should be saved in the `assets` folder.

**Third**: To read the file, you can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). If your `String`s don't have spaces in them, this would work:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("assets/foo.txt");

in.next();      // Read the next String
in.nextInt();   // Read the next int
in.nextFloat(); // Read the next float
```

If you have spaces in your `String`s, you should use commas and tell the `Scanner` to use `,`s as a delimiter:

```
Scanner in = ...;
in.useDelimiter(",");
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I am after. I am having trouble with the path to the file though. I have tried using "file:///android_asset/foo.txt" but that does not work. I have tried several methods by searching online, but no method seems to work. What am I missing?

Comment: FYI neither of these work either, they both force an IOException:
InputStream inStream = this.getAssets().open("foo.txt");
InputStream inStream = this.getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/foo.txt");

Comment: These examples do not work either, file.exsists() returns zero:
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/foo.txt");
File file = new File("foo.txt");

Comment: The path should be `assets/foo.txt`

Comment: This is just weird, that path does not work either. File file = new File("assets/foo.txt"); returns a zero value. Tried to upload an image of my directories to imgur for you to see, but it didn't work somehow. I have put the file directly in the "assets" folder that is automatically created in an Android project. The file is also in the file system in Ubuntu in the "assets" folder. I tried changing the contents of the file to just a word, but it didn't help. This shouldn't be a problem with APIs?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860873/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-android-assets-folder-in-the-application-package

Comment: I have tried following that example to no avail. I have updated my question with more code. Appreciate any help you may have!

Comment: I accept your answer since it is the correct one. I have moved the issue with reading the file [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674815/trouble-with-reading-file-from-assets-folder-in-android). Thanks for your efforts! :)

Answer (score 2):

Save it into your assets folder.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work fine. Can I then follow the example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml) and change the filename to "foo.txt" directly?

And when I have read a line, which methods can I use to read one and one string, float or int for that line?