# Trouble with reading file from assets folder in Android

Tags: java, android, readfile

This question is with regards to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657763/where-to-save-text-file-to-be-able-to-read-it-into-android-project). Since it is a specific question I moved that question by itself here. I have tried creating a text file, "foo.txt", an read it into my Activity doing:

```
File file = new File("/assets/foo.txt");
if ( file.exists() ){
    txtView.setText("Exists");
}
else{
    txtView.setText("Does not exist");
}
```

The "foo.txt" file is located in my assets folder and I have verified that it exists in the OS. My TextView always gets the text "Does not exist" from the code above. I have tried going

```
File file = new File("/assets/foo.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
```

as well, but this produces the following **inline** error: "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException". Eclipse then suggest to involve try/catch, which removes the error but it doesn't work properly then either.

I have also tried setting my assets folder to "Use as source folder", but this does not make any difference. I have also tried using a raw folder as several people suggests to no use. I am out of options and really need help for this one. Should be easy...

Another try is to go

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("assets/foo.txt");
```

but this produces the **inline** error in the second line: "Unhandled exception type IOException".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm with CommonsWare in that case (that's the safe side :) ), but it should be:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("foo.txt");
            if ( inputStream != null)
                Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Do not use `InputStream is = assetManager.open("assets/foo.txt");`

Comment: Still produces "Unhandled exception type IOException" when using only "foo.txt". I get the option to surround it with try/catch from Eclipse, but it makes no difference :(

Comment: Is there any change if you use `this.getAssets()` instead of `getResources().getAssets()`?

Comment: @Krøllebølle - also, please clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Ok, so I did clean the project and it suddenly works, not sure if it was the clean that made the trick or a good night sleep. BUT it has to be with try/catch statement as @imrankhan describes (Eclipse demands it). Thanks! \o/

Comment: I have try to read ".docx" file like this.Result is in encoded format..how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You do not access `assets/` at runtime using `File`. You access `assets/` at runtime using `AssetManager`, which you can get via `getResources().getAssets()`.

Comment: I have tried that as well, sorry for not mentioning it. I have updated my post.

Comment: @Krøllebølle: See the other answer -- you need to get rid of `assets/` in your path.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
    private AssetManager am;
     am=getAssets();

     InputStream inputStream = null ;  
        try   
        {  
            inputStream = am.open("read.txt");  
        }   
        catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: can you paste me full past of your file like yourprojectname/assets/filename??

Comment: Thank you, it works after I did the clean as @BinyaminSharet suggested. Eclipse demands try/catch around the inputStream = am.open("foo.txt"); and it works fin now. Thanks!