# Reading file from assets throwing FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, assets, filenotfoundexception

I'm using the following code:

```
    public void readLevel(int line){
    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = am.open("levelinfo.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");
    String skip;
    for(int i = 1; i < line; i++){
        skip = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    levelData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        levelData.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
}
```

The code is giving a FileNotFoundException. I've seen some similar problems, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it. The file is a text file inside the assets folder. Any help is appreciated

Andy

Comment: Oops! Error on my part, I saved the .txt file without the extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with reading file from assets folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674815/trouble-with-reading-file-from-assets-folder-in-android)