# Where to place pdf file in ti

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I recently asked a question relating to how to open a pdf file with a button in android development. Sorry for the vague question, but I will try to make this a little more specific. so I already have this code:

```
try {
    var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('your.pdf');
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
    type: 'application/pdf',
    data: f.getNativePath()
}));
catch (err) {
    var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
    title: //your text,
    message: // your text if not found,
    buttonNames: ['Yes','No'],
    cancel: 1
});
    alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.index == 0) {
    Ti.Platform.openURL('http://search?q=pdf');
}

});
```

However, I do not know where to place the "Your.pdf file". I tried the assets folder and I typed in

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('assets/your.pdf');
```

However, I get an error that says 'Invalid character constant'

Help? I hope this question was a little more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We generally place all of our loadable assets under resources, and use the relative paths from the resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can place files in assets folder. Use the following code to access your file.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

try {
    inputStream = assetManager.open("yourfile.txt");
        if ( inputStream != null)
            Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674815/trouble-with-reading-file-from-assets-folder-in-android) it shows the explanation.

Comment: This code is for native Android development, not Titanium (JavaScript).