# android read from a file from the assets folder

Tags: java, android

Im trying to read a file inside the assets folder
the exception which it throws is null

this method is in a class that is not extending any other class

```
   public boolean loadShader(String shaderFile, StringBuilder str) {

    try {
        File file = new File(shaderFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
            str.append('\n');
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage().toString();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're not reading from assets

Comment: Ah, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674815/trouble-with-reading-file-from-assets-folder-in-android?rq=1 for a similar question that could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(shaderFile);
```

This works only inside Activity, so you need a context to perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `getAssets()`

```
AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("shader.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor()));
```