# Location of prepackaged images

Tags: android

I have an image named `image01.png` packaged with my app under `res/drawable`. For reasons to be specified, I need to get the filepath for that image. I looked through the DDMS perspective on my emulator, but I can't seem to find the image. Where/how can I find the filepath for the image?

For people who don't mind "tl;dr": I'm trying to use the image as an overlay on mapview. However, the image is simply too large and it exceeds the 16MB budget allocated by Android. I found out that I can use BitmapRegionDecoder to load the image in bite-sized chunks but BitmapRegionDecoder uses either a filepath String, an InputStream, a FileDescriptor, or byte array to create new instances. Since this is an image that I will pre-package with the app, I didn't feel like using an InputStream was all that necessary. However, as mentioned above, I can't find the filepath for the image.

Comment: Is this something I should post on the Android SE instead? Technically, it's a programming question, but it has to deal with the Android OS file system, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: If you want to access a file directly, consider putting it in the /res/raw or /res/assets directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your All images in your project assets folder then you able to access it via file path like sdcard images.

Please Check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860873/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-android-assets-folder-in-the-application-package)

Think it help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that did it! For further reference, if I have a question similar to this one, do I post it here on SO or do I go to the Android SE?