# [Android Assets]: File or Folder?

Tags: android, file, uri, directory, assets

My Asset structure is divided in folders and files. When I open a file I need to know if is a file or folder. I need to know is the asset path I'm accessing if a file or a folder.

I'm trying to access the file through a method I'm implementing.

```
public int getFileType (String filepath)
{
    String PACKAGE_APP_NAME = /com/fake/android/app;
    File f = null; 

    try{
        //f = new File(new URI("file:///android_asset/" + JNI_CLASSES + "/" + filepath));   
        f = new File(new URI("file:///android_asset/" + filepath)); 
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {}

    if (f == null)
    {
        Log.e("ResListMaker","File Object Is Null");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (!f.exists())
    {
        Log.e("ResListMaker","File Doesn't Exist");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (f.isFile())
    {
        Log.e("ResListMaker","Regular File");
        return 0;
    }
        else if (f.isDirectory())
    {
        Log.e("ResListMaker","Directory");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("ResListMaker","Unknown type");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**But always return File Doesn't exist. Is the URI path right? Is there other way to know if the asset is file or a folder?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the wrong way to access your assets folder.

`InputStream is = getAssets().open("subfolder/somefile.txt");`

[Android Assets with SubFolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033902/android-assets-with-sub-folders)

Comment: Thanks man. Is there any way to know if the path that you are giving in open is a folder?

Comment: Yep, check out [list(somePath)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)) that will give you a list of assets in the directory you're looking at. If there isn't anything returned, then it's probably a directory.

Comment: I also though in checking the file stream size, if they are 0 they are directories, if they don't they are regular files.