# Can I add folders to Drawables and cycle files in them?

Tags: android

Wanted to ask how I can add my own folders with drawables to resources? And how could I later cycle through all files in a specific folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not. Unfortunately.

Probably, you can do so in assets folder as they do here [Android Assets with sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033902/android-assets-with-sub-folders)