# Android assets as a File

Tags: android, assets

I want to add a hierarchy of files to my android program and use all of them as files. Is it possible that I add them to my assets folder and then get Files and directories of the assets folder as Files? 
(for example if I have a pictures directory in my assets, the create a file which its path is pictures folder of assets).

Comment: Have you tried doing a search? Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033902/android-assets-with-sub-folders)

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you really need that for. You cannot access assets via `File` if you really need to so, then you can always copy assets content to local filesystem or storage and use it. Alternatively you can rethink how you use assets.