# android - Loading HTML from database into WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, local-storage

so i'm trying to load some HTML from my sqlite database into a webview.
This works splendid as the html is rendered beautifully but here comes the problem. The local file added in the html is not being load. I added it to the assets folder in this hierarchy: assets/folder1/folder2/placeholder.png but i get a Not allowed to load local resource: error. How can i get past this please.

Please note that the data is being populated from the db.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

That's the code for the web view above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body><h2 style="color:red;">Hello  Chief</h2><p>This is just a demo HTML content rendered beautifully</p><br><img src="file:///android_asset/folder1/folder2/placeholder.png"></body></html>
```

That's code above is for the data coming from the sqlite database.

My Assests folder looks something like this

```
-assets
  - folder1
    - folder2
      -file
```

Thanks

Comment: Please give a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033902/android-assets-with-sub-folders

Comment: how did you achieve that? (loading the html from sqlite to a web view). Could you share some code please?

Comment: oh wow, that's like almost a year ago @Mwas, all of the code is lost somewhere. But is just saving your html into the sqlite db and outputting it. Nothing out of the ordinary really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one method in webview to load html file with base url

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)
```

In baseUrl give it as

```
file:///android_asset/
```

Or else parse the html document with Jsoup and replace the src of required tags using Jsoup Parser.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now i get a Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/folder1/folder2/placeholder.png. Do i remove the (File) in my <img src="file:///android_asset/folder1/folder2/placeholder.png"> since its the base url now and link to it relatively? like <img src="/folder1/folder2/placeholder.png">